# Duplicate object in training set for traning object detection model

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

I prepared a dataset for training a object detection model (10 classes). I implied some people to help me in label annotation task. But when I assemble result from them, I had found that I sent many images to multiple people so those image contain many bounding boxes for same object. In case of some object, their bounding boxes that annotated by different people are not the same (They can be overlaped clearly, or only a part). So I have some questions:

- Will these bounding boxes affect detection performance of my model?
- If it will, how can I deal with this problem? Can I use an algorithm such as [Weighted box fusion](https://github.com/ZFTurbo/Weighted-Boxes-Fusion)
  to combine all bounding of an object to get the correct one?

Comment: Could you share a picture where these bounding boxes overlap or only partly overlap?